# Enforcing type safety of inherited members in inherited classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism

I’m trying to adhere to good OO design principles and design patterns and such. So while developing this C# application of mine I can often find multiple solutions to design and architecture issues, I always want to find and implement the more “canonical” one in the hopes of building highly maintainable and flexible software and also become a better OO programmer.

So suppose I have these two abstract classes: `Character` and `Weapon`.

```
abstract class Weapon
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

abstract class Character
{
    public Weapon weapon { get; set; }
}
```

Derived classes might be `Sword` and `Staff` from `Weapon`, and `Warrior` and `Mage` from `Character`, etc. (this is all hypothetical, not related to my actual software!).

Every `Character` has a `Weapon`, but for every implementation of `Character` I know what implementation of `Weapon` it will have. For instance, I know (and I want to enforce!) that at runtime every instance of `Warrior` will have a `Weapon` of type `Sword`. Of course I could do this:

```
class Sword : Weapon
{
    public void Draw() { }
}

class Warrior : Character
{
    public Warrior()
    {
        weapon = new Sword();
    }
}
```

But this way, every time I want to use my `Weapon` object properly inside a `Warrior`, I have to perform a cast, which I believe to be a not so great of a practice. Also I have no means to prevent myself from messing up, that is, there is no type safety!

An ideal solution would be to be able to override the `Weapon weapon` property in the `Warrior` class with a `Sword  weapon` property, that way I have type safety and if the user uses my `Warrior` as a `Character`, he can still use my `Sword` as a `Weapon`. Sadly, it doesn’t seem like C# supports this kind of construct.

So here are my questions: is this some kind of classical OO problem, with a name and a well-documented solution? In that case I would very much like to know the name of the problem and the solutions. Some links to good reading material would be very helpful! 
If not, what kind of class design would you propose in order to maintain functionality and enforce type safety in an elegant and idiomatic way?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: "every time I want to use my weapon object properly" - can you give an example of what is not 'properly'?

Comment: Properly meaning without needing a cast. Wouldn't you agree that if every time I use an object I have to cast it, there is something faulty in the design?

Comment: Agreed but I fail to see why you need to cast.

Comment: Because a Sword and a weapon wouldn't have the same interface. Sword would extend the interface of Weapon, adding new members and methods which I want to access from Warrior. Sorry if that wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that you are trying to capture the rules of dungeons and dragons *in the C# type system*. The type system is very simple; it was not designed to capture things like "a warrior is a kind of character that can only use a sword".

Comment: However there are other problems here. Why is "Draw" a method of "Sword"?  Drawing is something that is done *to* a sword, not *by* a sword. Suppose you had classes Salesperson and WashingMachine.  The WashingMachine does not have a "Sell" method; the Salesperson does the selling, the washing machine does the washing.

Comment: @Eric Both of your points are valid but do not actually matter as this example has nothing to do with my actual code, I might have as well called them class A and class B. Sorry, looks like I picked a bad example, even with the Draw method. I'm quite certain my actual code makes sense though!

Comment: As everybody take the words `Weapon` and `Character` you uses to argue why generics are not a good choice (and I completely agree with Eric's "a bowl of fruit" analogy), can you say us what are the real objects purposes you intend to implement ?

Comment: @Sharped I'm developing a CAD-like application, so I have a grid (Character) and on top of it I'll draw some objects. The grid is abstract (can be any type from several) and should have a GridParameters (Weapon) object which encloses some of the most important properties of it. So the parameters of the grid depend on the type of the grid. I know that my PolarGrid may not have a RectangularGridParameters object.

Comment: So it's a grid of objects ( "a bowl of fruits") : a CadGrid<CadObjects> Your GridParameters must be a virtual property / methods on CadGrid class, and RectangularGridParameters must be used in overridden property / methods on your RectangularGrid class.

Comment: @Sharped Exactly. But I don't use generics as in CadGrid<CadObjects>, the grid doesn't need to know what objects it has. I guess I'm using the Mediator Pattern: I have a Scene class which has the CadGrid object and a CadObjectsManager. The Scene class handles communication, it passes a reference of GridParameters to every CadObject so they know how to draw themselves.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UPDATE: This question was the inspiration for [a series of articles on my blog](http://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/). Thanks for the interesting question!

> is this some kind of classical OO problem, with a name and a well-documented solution?

The fundamental problem you're running into here is that it is difficult in an OO system to add a *restriction* to a *subclass*.  Saying "a character can use a weapon" and then "a warrior is a kind of character that can only use a sword" is hard to model in an OO system.

If you're interested in the theory behind this, you'll want to look for the "Liskov Substitution Principle". (And also any discussion of why "Square" is not a subtype of "Rectangle" and vice versa.)

There are however ways to do it. Here's one.

```
interface ICharacter
{
    public IWeapon Weapon { get; }
}
interface IWeapon {  }
class Sword : IWeapon { }
class Warrior : ICharacter 
{
    IWeapon ICharacter.Weapon { get { return this.Weapon; } }
    public Sword Weapon { get; private set; }
}
```

Now the *public* surface area of Warrior has a Weapon that is always a Sword, but anyone using the `ICharacter` interface sees a `Weapon` property that is of type `IWeapon`.

The key here is to move away from the "is a special kind of" relationship and move towards a "can fulfill the contract of" relationship. Rather than saying "a warrior is a special kind of character", say "a warrior is a thing that can be used when a character is required".

All this said, you are embarking upon a whole world of fascinating problems where you'll discover just how bad at representing these sorts of things OO languages really are.  You'll quickly find yourself deep in the double-dispatch problem and learning how to solve it with the Visitor pattern, once you start asking more complicated questions like "what happens when a warrior uses a sharp sword to attack an orc wearing leather armor?" and discover that you have *four* class hierarchies -- character, weapon, monster, armor -- all of which have subclasses that influence the outcome.  Virtual methods only allow you to dispatch on *one* runtime type, but you'll find that you need two, three, four or more levels of runtime type dispatch.

It gets to be a mess. Consider *not* trying to capture too much in the type system.

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks like I'll have to rethinks a couple of things. Would you say that C# is holding me back here? I mean, do you know of another language with a more powerful type system that would allow for this more naturally? (out of curiosity only)

Comment: @WHermann: C# has a pretty decent type system as these things go. If you genuinely have a multiple-dynamic-dispatch problem then languages like Dylan do a decent job of it. If you want to use generics, Scala has some slightly better covariance / contravariance support. Haskell's "higher types" are quite powerful as well.

Answer (score 9):

Just use [generics type constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) ! Here's an example

```
public abstract class Weapon
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface ICharacter
{
    Weapon GetWeapon();
}

public interface ICharacter<out TWeapon> : ICharacter
    where TWeapon : Weapon
{
    TWeapon Weapon { get; } // no set allowed here since TWeapon must be covariant
}

public abstract class Character<TWeapon> : ICharacter<TWeapon>
    where TWeapon : Weapon
{
    public TWeapon Weapon { get; set; }
    public abstract void Fight();
    public Weapon GetWeapon() { return this.Weapon; }
}

public class Sword : Weapon
{
    public void DoSomethingWithSword()
    {
    }
}

public class Warrior : Character<Sword>
{
    public override void Fight()
    {
        this.Weapon.DoSomethingWithSword();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting indeed! would you say this is idiomatic use of generics in C#?

Comment: Maybe i don't fully understand what you mean by "idiomatic", but generics are not specific to C#. You can also found generics in Java or in C++ (and many more languages I'm not aware of), but this is the C# syntax.

Comment: Never mind. This is a great answer and I think it might solve the issue, thanks!

Comment: Implementing your solution I found that I can't write something like: `Character<Weapon> MainCharacter = new Warrior();` Apparently one can't convert from `Character<Sword>` to `Character<Weapon>` implicitly nor explicitly. Any thoughts?

Comment: @WHermann: The feature you want is called *generic covariance*. C# allows covariance *only* in a very limited set of circumstances, and these circumstances are not it. The reason is of course the very problem that motivated the question: a `Character<Weapon>` can use *any* weapon, but a `Character<Sword>` can only use a *sword*, and therefore they are *not compatible types*. A bowl of bananas is not a bowl of fruit; you can put an apple into a bowl of fruit, but you can't put an apple into a bowl of bananas and have it stay a bowl of bananas.

Comment: @WHermann: As for your question about whether this is "idiomatic" -- it is unfortunately a *common* use of generics in C# but I cannot recommend it. We think of "a bowl of fruit", so it makes some sense to say that you can genericize bowls to different types of fruits. But we never say "a character of weapons", which suggests that generics are not a good fit for this business domain.

Comment: I was surprised to see this because I tried to do it myself after reading Eric's posts, but as it turned out "only interface and delegate type parameters can be specified as variant". Indeed this code does not compile, unless it's an extremely new feature! I'm using C# 2012 (.NET 4.5). Were you able to compile this?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, the out keyword must be placed on interface Type parameter : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx More info on covariance : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of documentation and future reference, I’m posting the solution that I’ll likely end up using:

```
abstract class Weapon {}

abstract class Character
{
    public abstract Weapon GetWeapon();
}

class Sword : Weapon {}

class Warrior : Character
{
    public Sword Sword { get; private set; }

    public override Weapon GetWeapon()
    {
        return Sword;
    }
}
```

As I see it, the only disadvantage is that objects of type Warrior have a `Sword Sword` property *and* a `Weapon GetWeapon()` method. In my case, this comes as a cosmetic problem only as both the property and the method return a reference to the same object when invoked.

Any comments are welcome!

Comment: Why not a `Weapon` get property, instead of a `GetWeapon()` method, in the `Character` class?

Comment: @drowa No particular reason, I guess either would work the same.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the "warriors can only use swords" restriction is not something that should be modeled in the type system.

You have "characters are things that have weapons"

```
abstract class Character {
   public Weapon weapon { get; set; }
}
```

but what you really want is to say something like "characters are things that have weapons, but with some restriction". I would suggest not having concrete types like "warrior" and "sword" at all, but rather those concrete types should be *instances*:

```
sealed class Weapon {
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

sealed class Character {
   const int sSkillToUseWeapon = 50;
   readonly Dictionary<string, int> mWeaponSkills = new Dictionary<string, int>();
   Weapon mCurrentWeapon;

   public Weapon CurrentWeapon {
      get {
         return mCurrentWeapon;
      } set {
         if (!mWeaponSkills.ContainsKey(value.Name))
            return;

         if (mWeaponSkills[value.Name] < mSkillToUseWeapon)
            return;

         mCurrentWeapon = value;
      }
   }

   public void SetWeaponSkill(string pWeaponName, int pSkill) {
      if (mWeaponSkills.ContainsKey(pWeaponName))
         mWeaponSkills[pWeaponName] = pSkill;
      else
         mWeaponSkill.Add(pWeaponName, pSkill);
   }
}
```

Then you can declare instances of them to use and reuse:

```
var warrior = new Character();
warrior.SetWeaponSkill("Sword", 100);
warrior.SetWeaponSkill("Bow", 25);

var archer = new Character();
archer.SetWeaponSkill("Bow", 125);
archer.SetWeaponSkill("Sword", 25);
archer.SetWeaponSkill("Dagger", 55);
//etc...
```

A `Warrior` is then an instance of Character with a particular set of weapon skills.

When you approach things this way, another issue you are bound to encouter is that there is a difference between, for example, "Rusty Sword" and "A Rusty Sword". In other words, even if "Rusty Sword" is an instance of "Weapon", there is still a difference between the general concept of "Rusty Sword", and an actual rusty sword that is lying on the ground. Same thing for "Goblin" or "Warrior".

The terms I use for these myself are "Stock____" and "Placed____", so there is a difference between a StockWeapon that defines a "class" of weapons, and a PlacedWeapon, which is an actual "instance" of a StockWeapon in the game world.

Placed objects then "have" instances of Stock objects, which define their common attributes (base damage, base durability, etc.), and have other attributes which define their current state independent of other similar items (location, durability damage, etc.)

([Here](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/) is a good site about using OOP patterns for game programming. (Oops I guess I forgot halfway through writing this that the game programming part was only an analogy. Nevertheless I did intend that hopefully the explanation would remain analogous.))

Comment: Now I really regret having used the D&D analogy! This is great but unfortunately does not apply to my actual problem. Anyways, +1 for the link, I highly enjoy anything OO patterns!

Comment: Can you clarify the Hungarian notation? s... m... p...? I don't think I have seen those before!

Comment: @WHermann i use s, m, p for static, instance member, parameter, respectively

Answer (score 0):

I think you are experiencing the lack of support in C# for [Covariant return type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type). Note you can see the `get` of a property as a special kind of method.